# Adding an item to cart for first time buyer

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, product

I have a WooCommerce Shop and I'm trying to add a specific Product to the Woocommerce cart for first Time buyers only. I have the following php code already.

**But for some reason, it won't work.**

This is my code:

```
add_action('woocommerce_before_cart','woocommerce_add_to_cart');

function woocommerce_add_to_cart(){
if(! is_admin()){
    global $woocommerce;

    $product_id=912;
    $found=false;
    $first_customer = false;

    if(is_user_logged_in()){
        $user_id=get_current_user_id();
        $customer_orders=get_posts(array(

        'meta_key' => '_customer_user',
        'meta_value' => $user_id,
        'post_type' => 'shop_prder',
        'numberposts' => -1
        ));

        if(count($customer_orders) > 0) {
            $first_customer=true;
            wc_add_notice( sprintf( "first custommer check",error));
            $statuses=array('wc-failed','wc-cancelled','wc-refunded');

            foreach($customer_orders as $tmp_orders){
                $order =wc_get_order($tmp_orders->ID);
                if (! in_array($order->get_status(),$statuses)){
                    wc_add_notice( sprintf( "first custommer tmp check",error));
                    $first_customer=false;
                }
            }
        }

        if ( sizeof( $woocommerce->cart->get_cart() ) > 0 ) {
            wc_add_notice( sprintf( "items in cart check",error));
        foreach ( $woocommerce->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $values ) {
        $_product = $values['data'];
        if ( $_product->id == $product_id ){
            wc_add_notice( sprintf( "produkt id check",error));
            $found = true;
                }
            }
        }

    }
    if (!$found && $first_customer){
            wc_add_notice( sprintf( "found and custommer check",error));
        WC()->cart->add_to_cart($product_id);
    }

  } 
}
```

I would really appreciate it if anyone could help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

There were 2 mistakes in your code and some other things:

- You were using an existing woocommerce hook to name your function
- the post_type is not **`'shop_prder'`** but **`'shop_order'`**

Here is that changed code:

```
// 'woocommerce_add_to_cart' is an existing woocommerce hook so you can't use it to name your custom function here…
add_action('woocommerce_before_cart','first_time_buyers');

function first_time_buyers(){
    if( !is_admin() && is_user_logged_in() ){

        $product_id = 912;
        $found = false;
        $first_customer = true;

        // Getting current customer valid orders (see 'post_status' below)
        $customer_orders=get_posts(array(
            'meta_key' => '_customer_user',
            'meta_value' => get_current_user_id(),
            'post_type' => 'shop_order', // <= NOT 'shop_prder' but 'shop_order'
            // We add the accepted orders status here
            'post_status' => array('wc-on-hold', 'wc-processing', 'wc-completed'),
            'numberposts' => -1
        ));

        if( count($customer_orders) > 0 )
            $first_customer = false;

        if ( !WC()->cart->is_empty() )
            foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item )
                if ( $product_id == $cart_item['product_id'] ) {
                    $found = true;
                    break;
                }

        if (!$found && $first_customer){
            WC()->cart->add_to_cart($product_id);
        }
    }
}
```

Code goes in any php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin php files.

This is tested and fully functional.